# How to convert Opencv single camera calibration matrix to Kitti format?

Tags: opencv, object-detection, camera-calibration, kitti

I am working with monocular 3D object detection. The GitHub repository uses the Kitti dataset and Kitti calibration matrix. P_rect_02 matrix from "calib_cam_to_cam.txt":

```
[ 718 0 607 45.3]  
[ 0 718 185 -0.113]  
[ 0  0   1  0.00377]
```

Now, I have one RGB camera, and using OpenCV camera calibration method (chessboard), I calculated the intrinsic matrix:

```
[803 0 529]  
[0 811 413]  
[0 0  1]
```

I also have a 3x1 rotational vector and a 3x1 translation vector. How can I convert my findings to the Kitti format? Kitti has stereo camera and according to the original paper, the projection matrix is:

```
[fu 0  cx  -fu*bx]  
[0  fv  cy -fv*by]  
[0   0   1  0]
```

where bx, by are distances between different cameras with respect to camera 0. I have only one camera. In that case, I do not have those distances. If I use 0 in the last column, the performance degrades.

Edit: Since only one RGB camera exists, 'bx' and 'by' will be 0 and the rests are the same as the intrinsic matrix. This gave me a fairly accurate result.

Comment: I guess kitti has the stereo calibration/rectification included? What exactly do you mean by converting the format? Do you want to make your image comparable to kitti images (which probably have a completely different perspective and form-factor)? Or do you need the calibration matrix for the monocular depth estimation?

Comment: since you only have a single camera there obviously is no stero-baseline. I guess you will have to understand how and why this information is still important for the monocular 3D thing, so how the DNN relates on that calibration information.

Comment: Since there is no baseline in a single RGB camera, 'bx' and 'by' will be 0 and rests are the same as the intrinsic matrix. That is what I found in the ros camera calibration package.